# Physical interpretation of Chern-Simons mass parameter?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, mass, mass-energy, chern-simons-theory

We have MCS Lagrangian
$$L_{MCS}=-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu\nu}+\frac{g}{2} \epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho}A_\mu\partial_\nu A_\rho,$$
where $g$ is mass parameter.

After bit of a maths we get
$$\left(\partial_\nu \partial^\nu+g^2\right)\widetilde{F}^\mu=0,$$
where $\widetilde{F}$ is dual field strength tensor $\widetilde{F}^\mu=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{ \nu \alpha \beta}F_{\alpha \beta}$, above relation explicitly shows $g$ as a mass parameter.

I want to know the physical significance and interpretation of this mass.

Can we say that the photons have mass in 2+1 D?

Is this the mass for $F^{\mu\nu}$ also?

What is the physical difference between $\widetilde{F}^\mu$ and $F^{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: 1. You're already calling it a mass. Do you have reason to believe it's not actually a mass? 2. Since the Hodge dual is a bijective map, why do you think there should be a "physical difference" between a field strength and its dual, since they encode the same information?

Comment: OP could you clarify a couple of things? 1. Do you mean Chern-Simons lagrangian or Maxwell lagrangian? 2. Chern-Simons theory is diffeomorphism invariant, yours is not (unless I'm reading you notation incorrectly).

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus Did you really mean "diffeomorphism invariant" in that comment (and not, say, "gauge invariant")?

Comment: @ACuriousMind yes, that's what I meant. OP's lagrangian contains 2 terms, the first one being a true diffeomorphism scalar and the second – a scalar density. OP has to multiply one of the terms (the scalar term) by an expression involving the spacetime metric ($\sqrt{|g|}$) to make his theory diffeo-invariant. Whereas in the usual Chern-Simons theory the lagrangian is already a scalar density, which means that Chern-Simons is diffeomorphism invariant without an external background spacetime (aka background independent).

Comment: @ACuriousMind you are right though that it is also not gauge invariant. However, I assume that OP is aware of this since he treats this lagrangian as a "mass term" modification of sorts (a point which I fail to grasp).

Comment: This is Maxwell-Chern-Simon Lagrangian. I have omitted the interaction part from it which makes it gauge invariant. The purpose of this post was to understand that can we say that photon field $A_\mu$ has a mass?